# Infer anonymous superclasses using SPIN rules

Tags: sparql, rule, inference, inference-engine, spin-rdf

I am building an ontology in TopBraidComposer which has a class hierarchy and a couple of rules that work great on their own. In my ontology, I'm working on a class level, so all the definitions I create only relate to classes, not individuals. Now I want to infer subclass definitions like this one:

[image: anonymous subclass]

I tried the following SPARQL query which seemed to do the job:

[image: SPARQL test]

Then I added said query as a SPIN rule to the owl:Thing class like this:

[image: SPIN rule 1]

After pressing enter, it is automatically converted to the following form:

[image: SPIN rule 2]

It looks reasonable but when I now start the inferencing process, it doesn't terminate anymore when it did before I added the test rule. When I force stop the reasoning, I can see that the desired triple has been added to the Test class numerous times.

How can I infer an anonymous superclass in SPIN?

**Edit:**

A workaround is to bind the restrictions to classes. The logic then seems to work but it doesn't show up like the anonymous superclasses do; neither in TBC nor in Protege.

Comment: The tag 'spin' is related to 'SPIN: A Formal Methods Technology'.  This does not appear to be your use of SPIN.  If not, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search, I found out the solution is really simple:

a simple check for an existing relationship will prevent an infinite loop:

```
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
  ?test rdfs:subClassOf _:b0 .
} .
```

which will be auto corrected by TBC to

```
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
  ?test rdfs:subClassOf _:0 .
} .
```

That's it, the rule will work.

Comment: I think the correction is because of the fact that you can't re-use  blank nodes so you would probably have to type the restriction with the blank node into the CONSTRUCT and the WHERE clause.